# Best practice for cleaning up EntityStoppedManifest journal entries for permanently terminated actors?

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-persistence

In our actor system, using sharding and persistence, the concrete instances of one of our `ReceivePersistentActor` implementations are not re-used once they are terminated (passivated), as they represent client sessions identified by a GUID that is generated for each new session.

When a session ends, the `ReceivePersistentActor` is responsible for cleaning up it's own persistence data and will call `DeleteSnapshots` and `DeleteMessages`, which works fine. Once these calls have been processed, the actor will `Context.Parent.Tell(new Passivate(PoisonPill.Instance));` to terminate.
After that, the event journal will still contain an `EntityStoppedManifest` entry (`"CD"`), as this is generated through the `Passivate` message.
Over time this will lead to many `"CD"` entries remaining in the event journal.

Is there a recommended approach for cleaning up such residue entries?
Maybe a separate Janitor actor that cleans up these entries manually?
Or is this even a design flaw on our end?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I came here too hastily, as those events have been mostly cleaned up by now *automagically*.

What might have been the issue for those events to accumulate in such high numbers in the first place was that these events had been generated during actor recovery instead of during normal operation. But this is just an assumption.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).